# Maximise the given equation in less than O(n^2)

Tags: algorithm, adhoc

Given an array how to find the max value of

```
    (ar[j]-ar[i]-1)*(min(ar[i],ar[j]))
```

in time O(n) or O(nlogn)

Comment: Why think this is even possible? Also -- are there any constraints on the numbers such as being all positive?

Comment: Yes the elements of the array are all positive . This is a previous olympiad problem therefore it is possible to do it.I forgot the solution i saw a few years back.

Comment: Okay -- I didn't have a strong intuition that it was impossible but wasn't convinced it was possible. If the numbers are all positive then the `-1` is superfluous since the expression is maximized at the same pair of indices which maximizes the expression with the negative 1 deleted (at least if all the numbers are not the same). I'm not sure how that helps, but simpler expressions are typically easier to optimize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input is always nonnegative, then there is no point in using anything but the maximum element of `ar` as `ar[j]`; any product that doesn't use `ar[j]` there can be increased by using `ar[j]`. Thus, we can find the maximum value in `O(n)` time and try it against all possible values of `ar[i]` in `O(n)` time to solve the problem.

If the input is not required to be nonnegative, the maximum product must use the maximum `ar[j]` or the minimum `ar[j]`. Again, we can find the maximum and the minimum and try them against all possible `ar[i]` values.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure about finding `i` in `O(n)` time, as it seems to require multiplication: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations

Comment: @SamBurns: It seems pretty clear to me that we're assuming constant-time arithmetic. If we're *not*, then we're assuming variable-size integers, in which case the input could be bigger than `O(n^2)` (where n is the number of input elements) and we wouldn't have a hope of solving the problem in time. In any case, we don't need multiplication to find `i`; with a fixed `j`, the expression to maximize is a simple quadratic. We can find the vertex once and pick the `i` closest to that.

Comment: Yeah, you're completely right. Ignore me, and do this instead: Pick the highest value possible for `ar[j]`, by iterating through the array once in `O(n)` time. Then find the value of `ar[i]` which is closest to `(ar[j] - 1)/2)`, again in `O(n)` time, giving the highest possible value for your expression in `O(n)` time overall.